# Find the solution from a word search game

Tags: python

I have a file with a matrix that is my wordsearch and some words that i need to find in it.

```
O   T   N   E   G   R   A   S   A   E
R   N   N   C   O   R   A   L   L   O
O   A   I   B   L   U   E   E   V   G
U   T   O   R   E   N   T   I   I   A
V   I   O   L   E   T   T   O   O   R
O   C   R   A   R   I   A   E   L   O
D   A   B   I   M   A   L   V   A   P
I   P   C   I   E   L   O   G   L   R
C   O   R   P   O   S   O   U   A   O
A   P   I   E   N   O   M   I   L   P


ACIDO
ARGENTO
BLU
CIELO
CORALLO
CORPOSO
ELETTRICO
LATTE
LIMONE
MALVA
NERO
OCRA
OPACITA
ORO
PAGLIERINO
PIENO
PORPORA
PRIMITIVO
VIOLA
VIOLETTO
```

For the solution I have thought about something like that:

```
 with open('cp5_Colori.txt', 'r') as f:
        import pprint
        data=f.read().replace("\t","")
        A=[]
        B=set()
        data=data.split("\n\n")
        word_list=data[1].split()
        lista_orizzontale=data[0].split()
        puzzle=[list(row) for row in lista_orizzontale]
        for parola in word_list:
            for lista in puzzle:
                x=puzzle.index(lista)
                for carattere in lista:
                    y=lista.index(carattere)
                    if carattere.upper() == parola[0]:
                        for direction in [(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(-1,1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1)]:
                            (dx, dy) = direction
                            for i in range(len(parola)):
                                if ((x+dx*i)<len(puzzle)) and ((y+dy*i)<len(lista)) == True:
                                    if puzzle[x+dx*i][y+dy*i].upper()== parola[i]:
                                        puzzle[x+dx*i][y+dy*i]=puzzle[x+dx*i][y+dy*i].lower()







        pprint.pprint(puzzle)
```

To solve the puzzle you need to search and then delete from the wordsearch all the OCCURRENCES (if multiple) of the words in the list.

The letters of the diagram that will remain, taken all in their order by rows and by columns, they will form the solution of the game.
I don't know how to continue and how to find the solution that is "SANGUEBLU"

Comment: Rather than `.read()`, I wold look into using numpy's [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to get the characters into an actual array, then you can use slicing to get the rows and columns and check whether they contain the words

Comment: Mind not vandalising your question?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following initialization:

```
puzzle = [l.split() for l in '''O   T   N   E   G   R   A   S   A   E
R   N   N   C   O   R   A   L   L   O
O   A   I   B   L   U   E   E   V   G
U   T   O   R   E   N   T   I   I   A
V   I   O   L   E   T   T   O   O   R
O   C   R   A   R   I   A   E   L   O
D   A   B   I   M   A   L   V   A   P
I   P   C   I   E   L   O   G   L   R
C   O   R   P   O   S   O   U   A   O
A   P   I   E   N   O   M   I   L   P'''.splitlines()]

word_list = '''ACIDO
ARGENTO
BLU
CIELO
CORALLO
CORPOSO
ELETTRICO
LATTE
LIMONE
MALVA
NERO
OCRA
OPACITA
ORO
PAGLIERINO
PIENO
PORPORA
PRIMITIVO
VIOLA
VIOLETTO'''.splitlines()
```

The following code will solve your problem:

```
from itertools import product
removals = []
for word in word_list:
    for row in range(len(puzzle)):
        for col in range(len(puzzle[row])):
            for dr, dc in product(range(-1, 2), repeat=2):
                if dr or dc:
                    removal = []
                    for i in range(len(word)):
                        r = row + dr * i
                        c = col + dc * i
                        if not (0 <= r < len(puzzle) and 0 <= c < len(puzzle[row])) or puzzle[r][c] != word[i]:
                            break
                        removal.append((r, c))
                    else:
                        removals.append(removal)
for removal in removals:
    for row, col in removal:
        puzzle[row][col] = None
print(''.join(char for row in puzzle for char in row if char))
```

This outputs:

```
SANGUEBLU
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you downcased the letter using your code, you can get the result by:

```
crossed = [['o', 't', 'n', 'e', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'S', 'a', 'e'], ['r', 'n', 'n', 'c', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o'], ['o', 'a', 'i', 'b', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'e', 'v', 'g'], ['U', 't', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 'i', 'a'], ['v', 'i', 'o', 'l', 'e', 't', 't', 'o', 'o', 'r'], ['o', 'c', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'o'], ['d', 'a', 'b', 'i', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'v', 'a', 'p'], ['i', 'p', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'G', 'l', 'r'], ['c', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'o', 's', 'o', 'U', 'a', 'o'], ['a', 'p', 'i', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'm', 'i', 'l', 'p']]

import re
result = ''.join([ ''.join(line) for line in crossed ])
print(result)
hidden_word = ''.join(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', result))
print (hidden_word) #=> SUGU
```

But it seems you code downcased too many words.

Comment: thank you sir.. yeah i need also diagonals... but i alredy know how to find the words.. my problem is to find the remaining characters  that is the solution of the game ,after deleting all the found words

Comment: Smart downcase found letters, here is how to retrieve the result, but somehing is wrong.

Comment: thank you for your help , but the solution should  be "SANGUEBLU" not "SUGU".. what's wrong in my code? how can i fix it?